# Exceção ao executar cláusula UPDATE no IBM DB2

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2, ibm

Olá, estou fazendo um UPDATE num banco de dados IBM DB2, e está me retornando essa mensagem:

```
DB2 query node, error in query: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0100W  Não foi localizada uma linha para FETCH, UPDATE ou DELETE, ou o resultado de uma consulta é uma tabela vazia.  SQLSTATE=02000
```

Olhei a documentação de exceções na IBM Knowledge Center, porém não encontrei uma solução. Verifiquei também as causas possíveis que podem estar ocasionando esse warning, porém não cheguei a lugar nenhum. Estou deixando passar alguma coisa...

A cláusula de UPDATE que eu tenho é a seguinte:

```
UPDATE BLUADMIN."AlarmEvent" SET "NormTime" = CASE 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 0 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 1 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 2 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 3 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 4 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 5 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '16' AND "Array" = 6 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 7 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 8 THEN 20200327065645 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065645 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 9 THEN 20200327065645 
END WHERE "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 8 AND "Array" IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) AND "TagName" IN ('0')
```

A tabela que estou tentando atualizar possui dados. Queria saber se tem algo de errado na cláusula que possa estar ocasionando o warning citado acima.

Nessa outra cláusula, eu obtenho sucesso:

```
UPDATE BLUADMIN."AlarmEvent" SET "NormTime" = CASE 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 0 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 1 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 2 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 3 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 4 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 5 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 6 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = '0' AND "Array" = 7 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "EventValue" != '0' AND "Array" = 8 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = 'Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b10' AND "Array" = 9 THEN 20200327065756 
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = 'Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b12' AND "Array" = 9 THEN 20200327065756    
    WHEN "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "ActiveTime" != 20200327065756 AND "TagName" = 'Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b13' AND "Array" = 9 THEN 20200327065756 
END WHERE "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C000000-15-000200' AND "DeviceType" = 'Inverter' AND "Index" = 15 AND "Array" IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) AND "TagName" IN ('0','Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b10','Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b12','Inverter[15].MPPT2_Event2.b13')
```

Lembrando que a tabela possui dados para ambos os indexes(8 e 15).

Se tiverem sugestões de melhoria na cláusula, estou aberto a críticas. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Me parece que é apenas um aviso informando que nenhuma linha de sua tabela atende aos critérios especificados.

Comment: De fato é só um warning, mas o update não está atualizando o que deveria atualizar.

Comment: Vou mudar algumas coisas na aplicação para fazer de uma maneira melhor.

Comment: Mas se nenhuma linha atende aos critérios especificados ele vai atualizar o quê? Talvez os critérios não tenham sido codificados corretamente.

Comment: Em 1 dos WHEN que a claúsula possui, as condições são true, portanto deveria atualizar algum dado da tabela. Não coloquei na pergunta, mas são updates válidos que atualizam algo, no caso o 1° UPDATE não está atualizando, e o 2° da sucesso.

Comment: Não é a cláusula WHEN que você deve verificar e sim a cláusula WHERE.

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Tem algum exemplo?